# SwiftUI onDismiss not firing when presenting a sheet (Xcode Beta 5)

Tags: swiftui, ios13

In SwiftUI I am trying to get some code to run after a sheet has been dismissed but the 'onDismiss' closure in not called.

I'm running Xcode Beta 5, with an IOS 13 build target

```
import SwiftUI

struct ModalView : View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Text("Modal view")
            Button(action: { print("Dismiss button pressed"); self.presentationMode.value.dismiss() }) { Text("Dismiss") }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModal: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.showModal = true }) { Text("Show modal via .sheet modifier") }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal, onDismiss: { print("Modal Dismissed") }) { ModalView() }


    }
}
```

I should see:

```
Dismiss Button Pressed
Modal Dismissed
```

but I only get

```
Dismiss Button Pressed
```

Am I doing something stupid or is this another beta issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. `onDismiss` is called when you use the swipe gesture to dismiss the modal view (as you would expect), but it isn't called when you use `self.presentationMode.value.dismiss()` to dismiss the modal view, which just seems like a bug to me. I don't see any reason why your code shouldn't work.

A workaround in the meantime could be to pass an `onDismiss` closure to your `ModalView`, and then call it after calling `self.presentationMode.value.dismiss()`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try the swipe method as I'm trying to implement a login sheet. I think I'll file a radar for this one.

Comment: @lidders filed feedback for this one as well